# How to prevent clicking an underlying checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, checkbox

i have 2 checkboxes and a third one which acts as a "toggle all". I have the following criterias:

- When none of the other 2 checkboxes are checked, the "toggle all" should be unchecked as well.
- When both of the other 2 checkboxes are checked, the "toggle all" should be checked as well.
- When only one of the other checkboxes is checked, the "toggle all" should be checked and disabled to display a "half-checked" state.

Also, it should be possible to click the "toggle all" to check or uncheck the other 2 (if "toggle all" is half-checked, both should be checked).

I created the following JS/jQuery function:

```
function setPdfDialogPriceCheckboxes(pElement)
{
    var tSuperCheckbox = jQuery("#superCheckbox").next();
    var tCheckbox1 = jQuery("#checkbox1");
    var tCheckbox2 = jQuery("#checkbox2");

    console.log(pElement.id);

    if(pElement.id == "superCheckbox")
    {
        tSuperCheckbox.click();
        var tCheckAll = tSuperCheckbox.is(':checked');
        if(tCheckbox1.is(':checked') != tCheckAll)
        {
            tCheckbox1.click();
        }
        if(tCheckbox2.is(':checked') != tCheckAll)
        {
            tCheckbox2.click();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(tCheckbox1.is(':checked') && tCheckbox2.is(':checked'))
        {
            tSuperCheckbox.prop('checked', true);
            tSuperCheckbox.prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else if(tCheckbox1.is(':checked') || tCheckbox2.is(':checked'))
        {
            tSuperCheckbox.prop('checked', true);
            tSuperCheckbox.prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else
        {
            tSuperCheckbox.prop('checked', false);
            tSuperCheckbox.prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the "toggle all" checkbox has an overlaying div preventing direct clicking on it so i can handle onclick()-Events even when the checkbox is disabled:

```
<div style="position: relative; ">
    <div id="superCheckbox" onclick="setPdfDialogPriceCheckboxes(this)" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 9999; "></div>
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

I created a fiddle for this here: http://jsfiddle.net/9mhag8b6/

It works on Firefox and Chrome, but Internet Explorer seems to simply ignore the overlaying div and lets me directly click the checkbox.

I know i could probably use "indeterminate" to show the half-checked state on the checkbox, but i'd rather have it this way. My current workaround is to use an image instead but that looks the same way on all browsers while checkboxes differ.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: *"Also, the "toggle all" checkbox has an overlaying div preventing direct clicking on it"* Why would you do that? Just prevent the click.

Comment: why wouldn't you use `<label>` instead of `div` and take advantage of default label click behavior for checkbox? What you are doing is overcomplicated and trying to re-invent the wheel

Comment: Since the toggle-all checkbox can (and will) get disabled when only one of the other checkboxes is checked, it won't be able to trigger onclick()-events. Thus, the div handling the events instead. The same for label, it probably won't do anything since the checkbox is disabled.

Comment: why wouldn't you bind handlers to checkbox? Approach makes no sense

Comment: I tried this at well, but handlers won't trigger on a disabled checkbox. At least not on Firefox so i didn't bother testing for other browsers.

Comment: There should also be labels around the text next to the checkbox - users expect that clicking the text clicks the checkbox. It would help if you didn't use a table to lay out that simple indent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/9mhag8b6/6/

To avoid the problem of not being able to click a disabled checkbox, let's just make it semi-transparent instead.

You said you used Jquery, which you did in part. Here it is using jQuery to its full extent.

I used this HTML, with classes, labels and no onlick event. There's no need for IDs on every checkbox, you only need to specifically identify the "super checkbox" out of all of them. 
You really should avoid assigning ids to everything and referencing them separately in your javascript when their function is synonymous, e.g. `if (checkbox1.is(':checked') && checkbox2.is(':checked'))`  - it makes your code far more untidy and unnecessarily larger than it needs to be.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" class="setPdfDialogPriceCheckboxes" id="superCheckbox" /> Preisanzeige</label>
<div class="indent">
    <label><input class="setPdfDialogPriceCheckboxes" type="checkbox" /> Preis</label>

    <label><input class="setPdfDialogPriceCheckboxes" type="checkbox" /> Ø-Preis</label>

</div>
```

JQuery. By using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` we don't have to `.trigger('change')` which would cause a recursive problem. You will also see that you can chain events, rather than write code like `tSuperCheckbox.prop('checked', true); tSuperCheckbox.prop('disabled', false);`. The `$` in variable assignment denotes that it's a jQuery object, it's not necessary, it's a preference.

```
$(function(){
    $('.setPdfDialogPriceCheckboxes').on('change', function(){
        // assign these to make it easier to read and not look up > once
        var $superCheckbox = $('#superCheckbox');
        var $checkboxes = $('.setPdfDialogPriceCheckboxes').not($superCheckbox);
        // create a reduced list of the ones that are checked
        var $checkboxes_checked = $checkboxes.map(function(){ 
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) return true;
        });

        // supercheckbox does something different to the rest
        if ($(this).is($superCheckbox)){
            var check;
            // ignore current status of this checkbox, check all if < all are checked
            if ($checkboxes_checked.length == $checkboxes.length){
                // they are all checked
                check = false;
            }else{
                check = true;
            }

            $checkboxes.add($superCheckbox).prop({checked: check});
            $superCheckbox.css({opacity: 1});
        }else{
            // are they all checked?
            if ($checkboxes_checked.length == $checkboxes.length){
                // all checked
                $superCheckbox.prop({checked: true}).css({opacity: 1});
            }else if (!$checkboxes_checked.length){
                // none checked
                $superCheckbox.prop({checked: false}).css({opacity: 1});
            }else{
                // some checked
                 $superCheckbox.prop({checked: true}).css({opacity: 0.5});

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I like this solution in general, but there a 2 small bugs: The opacity doesn't get reset when the super checkbox gets clicked and when only some checkboxes are checked, clicking the super checkbox will uncheck them all where it should check them instead. I will probably take this one and work on from here.

Comment: I see, it unchecks because it is checked before it's clicked. You can use the count of those that are checked to tell it to "uncheck if all are checked else check"

Comment: The opacity thing, just add the line `$superCheckbox.css({opacity: 1});` after `$checkboxes.prop({checked: $(this).is(':checked')});`

Comment: Also if you want to apply this to several different sets of checkboxes on a page, it only takes a few minor changes (not the duplication of code).

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of graying out the "check all" you just fadeout a bit, on that way you still  have a clickable checkbox.
Heres a quick example:

```
/* CSS */ 
#toggle-all{
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  z-index: 9999;
} 
.some-toggle { /* you can add more styles if necessary */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50); /*IE*/ 
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* HTML */
<label id="toggle-all">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-all-checkbox"> Toggle All 
</label>
<div> 
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"> Checkbox 1 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"> Checkbox 2 </label>
</div>

/* JS */
$("#toggle-all-checkbox, #checkbox1, #checkbox2").on('click', function(){
  if (this.id == 'toggle-all-checkbox') {
    $('#checkbox1, #checkbox2').prop('checked', this.checked);
  } else {
    var checked1 = $('#checkbox1').prop('checked'),
        checked2 = $('#checkbox2').prop('checked');
    if (checked1 && checked2) {
      $('#toggle-all-checkbox').removeClass('some-toggle').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      if (!checked1 && !checked2)
        $('#toggle-all-checkbox').removeClass('some-toggle').prop('checked', false);
      else
        $('#toggle-all-checkbox').addClass('some-toggle').prop('checked', true);
    }
  }
});
```

I haven't test this code but I hope it gives you another idea on how to approach this